# Libraries for high performance, low footprint graph queries?

Tags: performance, graph, relational-database, java

I am so close to implementing this myself, but before I do I would still want to know if that wheel already has been invented: what I need is a library that allows me to represent a DAG (directed acyclic graph) and which will allow to make queries about directly or indirectly connected nodes with very high performance. I have compared two approaches so far.

The graph will be a couple of millions of nodes in size with about 10-20 million edges. Most nodes will only have one or two edges but a couple of thousand nodes may have 10000 edges or more.

The use case would be: does not really matter what the effort to create the graph is, and once it has been created it does not need to get updated, or updates need not be fast.
However, finding direct connections or specific indirect connections of length 2 (one intermediate node) should be very fast and edges should be able to have labels (e.g. weights, counts etc.). Also, the memory footprint should be small and querying should be thread-safe.

I have experimented with using some standard software packages for this, e.g. Neo4J or relational databases, but both are way too slow for some of the things: relational databases grind to a crawl for finding indirect relations when nodes with a lot of edges are involved (huge join sets). Neo4j handles that case much better, but the basic speed of just finding a direct connection is thousands of times slower than in relational database solutions. On a workstation, relational databases can return results for direct and many indirect queries in less then 5ms, but certain indirect queries can take up to a minute. With Neo4j on the same system, those indirect queries just take a few seconds, but the direct queries all take longer than 100ms. I want to be able to get my direct queries to under one ms and the worst indirect ones to under 1 second (on average).

I think when done cleverly, this could all be represented and carried out in-memory with just a few gigs of heap space, and even for bigger graphs, there would be strategies to do these things very fast by clever caching and a clever way of how to persist parts of the graph to disk. But I could not find any solution or library (preferable open source) which would offer this. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

A graph with millions of nodes and tens of millions of edges will fit trivially in memory on any desktop computer made this century.  I would suggest using the FORTRAN-style

```
int ia[NVERT+1];
int ja[NEDGE];
```

where the edges are sorted by tail vertex, the edges with tail at `v` have indices `ia[v]` up to `ia[v+1]-1`, and `ja[e]` lists the head end of the `e`th edge.  Note that this takes about `4(NVERT+NEDGE+1)` bytes of memory, which is considerably less than "just a few gigs."

Checking whether there is an edge from one vertex to another is simple; you look at the outgoing edges from the first vertex.  Checking whether there is a two-edge path from one vertex to another is also simple; you find all the neighbours of the first vertex and check whether any of them have an outgoing edge pointed at the second vertex.  This is, at worst, a scan through all your edges.  Doing this yourself is also almost certainly less code than what it takes to connect to a database.

No software that takes more than a few milliseconds for either type of query you've described is worth using for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks - that is about what I had in mind when I said "close to implementing it myself" ;)
That must have been implemented hundreds of times already, so I simply had been wondering if there is completed solution available in the form of a library.

Comment: @Johsm: It's certainly been implemented hundreds of times already.  Unfortunately, when people try to make it into an all-singing, all-dancing "database", efficiency goes, as you saw, straight down the toilet.  Most scientific code that cares about graphs reimplements graphs in a way that suits the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it fits your requirements, as I did not use this library myself, but maybe GUERY, a framework designed by an ex-colleague of mine from NZ is worth a look: https://code.google.com/p/gueryframework/